# Resizing Java Internal Frame by its sides on MacOS

Tags: java, frame

How do you resize an internal frame by its sides on MacOs? Setting the resizable flag to true only makes an internal frame resizable when the cursor is placed on its bottom right corner. The same issue does not occur in Windows operating system. That is, you can resize an internal frame by placing the cursor anywhere along its sides (edges). This issue seems only related to MacOs. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Below is a sample Java code (Copyright HerongYang.com) which I've compiled and tested on MacOs High Sierra 10.13.6. Placing the cursor on the sides of the internal frames to resize it does not work. The only way the internal frames can be resized is if the cursor is placed at their bottom right corner. I tried other similar
sample Java programs and none of them work when the cursor is placed elsewhere. The same Java code works perfectly well on Windows operating system.

```
/* JInternalFrameTest.java
* Copyright (c) HerongYang.com. All Rights Reserved.
*/
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class JInternalFrameTest {
public static void main(String[] a) {
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Internal Frames");
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myFrame.setSize(300,300);
JDesktopPane myDesktop = new JDesktopPane();
myFrame.setContentPane(myDesktop);
JInternalFrame f = createFrame("Frame 1");
f.setLocation(10,10);
myDesktop.add(f);
f = createFrame("Frame 2");
f.setLocation(60,60);
myDesktop.add(f);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
}
private static JInternalFrame createFrame(String t) {
JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame(t);
f.setResizable(true);
f.setClosable(true);
f.setMaximizable(true);
f.setIconifiable(true);
f.setSize(200,200);
f.setVisible(true);
return f;
}
}
```

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Then other Mac users can confirm if they have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks—I added a sample Java code if anyone wants to test what I asserted.